What excel formula do I need to map/track my mortgage payments?
Given an interest rate of 4.06% with a regular monthly payment of £977.02 (last 2 payments of £1,977.02) what formula do I need to match the displayed data?
My formulas get pretty close but it should be exact. I’ve tried to map it using the PMT functionality and manually using:
balance * 4.06% / 12 months

balance * 4.06% / 365 * days in month

And also an approach which tries to work it out splitting the month into two periods… one before the interest payment and one after it.
All of them result in a value within a couple of £ but I want it to be exact.




neither of those formula(s) will calculate APR properly. There is an Excel formula for that =RATE (nper, pmt, pv)*12.  As you make additional payments and pay down the interest, eventual you stop paying the interest, this also means eventually the interest portion of your monthly payment decreases. Neither of those formulas take that into consideration. What does not work about the Excel formula? Furthermore, every year the amount of interest you pay, will be based on the number of principal payments you make.

=PMT(rate, nper, pv, [fv], [type]) also exists.

This all depends on how your bank calculates interest, what basis they use, whether they compound or just calculate daily, and so on. The only way to know for sure it to read the mortgage documentation in detail or specifically ask pointed questions to the bank.

@FlexYourData - How you calculate a mortgage payments isn’t bank specific. There is a reason Excel has a built-in function to calculate it.

@Ramhound, the calculation differs by region. https://business.sdsu.edu/research/_files/_realestate/international-comparison-mortgage.pdf, and there are fixed and variable rate mortgages. Trying to match what the bank expects by performing your own calculations in a spreadsheet could lead to an unfortunate surprise.

Given the information in my question it is perfectly possible to work out the formula required, unfortunately it's well beyond my abilities - thank you to @MGonet who gave a perfect answer.

Based on the data presented, it can be seen that the calculation of interest is carried out in accordance with the following rules:

The year is divided into days according to the calendar, that is, the year 2024 into 366 days, not 365 days.
Interest accrues on the last day of the month, but capitalized at the beginning of the following month.
Cash repayment is credited on the date of payment, i.e. the interest for this day is already lower.
Monthly interest is rounded up to 1 penny.



Absolute perfect answer - I wish I could upvote more, thank you.
